# Latest Mule ESB plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, esb, mule

Is there any official Mule plug-in for Eclipse?

I found only this one http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/muleide/updates/ but it is for Mule 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the documentation about how to install Mule IDE [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3INSTALL/Installing+Mule+ESB+3+and+the+Mule+IDE). Bear in mind that Mule IDE has been discontinued in favor of Mule Studio as explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3STUDIO/Studio+FAQ)